# Translucent-Overlays configuration

Tags: openldap

is anyone familiar on how setting translucent overlay for openldap 2.4.40.
I searched the internet without any hope.

what I want to implement is two openldap server so that one server get the search information from the other one, override some information based on its database and then give the final attributes

Comment: But did you read the [documentation](http://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-translucent&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenLDAP+2.4-Release&format=html)?

Comment: @EJP yes I did ...

Comment: And? So? Your question?

Answer (score 2):

His question would be "How do you start". I've also read the "documentation"; it's terrible on this subject.

The slapo-translucent man page has no effective information other than "this is the translucent overlay, you can enable it." There's nothing about how you configure it to point to the remote ldap server. There's very little information
on how you can determine what cn/dn/du/o/fu that you desire to add/modify about the remote search results. (I just want to add to a user's group membership and
there isn't an example about something as simple as that.)

Everything regarding OpenLDAP 2.4 says you should be using ldapadd/modify to change the slapd dynamic configuration in /etc/ldap/slapd.d and yet ALL examples/tutorials for translucent overlays reference outdated slapd.conf usage.

Basically, none of the documentation is in any way educational unless you are already a full wizard at administering OpenLDAP.

Add to that the community documentation comes from a wide flavor of unix distributions, none of which conform to each other, and it just maximizes
the confusion.

My interaction with OpenLDAP leaves me with the impression that it has, easily, the most confusing configuration and usage architecture of any service that I have ever seen.

A directory service is something that an admin should be able install and standup in a day with no prior experience. It's clearly going to take weeks of
time trying to untie the configuration knot that this requires.